# Will installer automatically use new empty disk or try to partition my Win 10 disk?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, ssd

I have been running Ubuntu 14.04 using Virtual Box on my Win 10 machine for a number of months. I am now spending the majority of my time in Ubuntu except when gaming so I have decided I am going to properly dual boot my PC.

I have installed an empty 256GB SSD into my computer so that Ubuntu 14.04 can be installed into it while my other SSD will remain untouched with my Win 10 + games.

My noob question is ... will the 14.04 installer automatically use the empty second SSD that I have installed or will I have to do some kind of advanced install and setup partitions myself? If I have to do an advanced install do you have any pointers/tips to make my journey 'smooth'?

My Win 10 install is UEFI.

Many Thanks!

Simon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boot from Ubuntu installation media.
Select Try Ubuntu without installing.

On the desktop - click Install Ubuntu.
When asked choose Something else.

Create a new partition on the SSD - choose a size that fits your needs.
Select / (root) as mount point and ext4 as file system.

Create a new partition on the SSD - choose a size matching your RAM.
Select swap for formatting.

For the boot loader installation select the disk where Windows is installed.
The GRUB boot loader will be installed to the already existing EFI partition.

Note :

I assume that you have sufficient RAM and as you want to install to a SSD,
in case you do not want to hibernate, you do not need the swap partition.

Comment: I am now replying from my freshly installed Ubuntu :) Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

> will the 14.04 installer automatically use the empty second SSD that I have installed

No.

> or will I have to do some kind of advanced install and setup partitions myself?

No.

> If I have to do an advanced install do you have any pointers/tips to make my journey 'smooth'?

You can pick "unallocated space" and have the system do the rest. But you can also pick "something else" and do it yourself.

For starters pick the 1st option. In the future when you get better with this you might want to decided on a partition setup you like.

-all- partition methods are fine as long as / is something like 20Gb or more. You can use 1 big part, use 1 for root and 1 for /home, or no /home, use a part for a /data/ disk. It will all work and it is more of a preference.

My preference: I like my personal data on a separate partition (/discworld/). My /home/$USER/ directories are on that partition so I just copy "users-dirs.dirs" over and all is set as I need it to be. A format of my system I can do at any time where I do not need to worry about contents of / and /home/. Just got to make sure I never format my /discworld/ partition.

Depending on your preferences: I would not use a swap on an SSD. It is is a notebook consider not using hibernation/suspend and always turn of the machine. SSD will take 7 seconds(-ish) to boot.